# mobile number validation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript code for mobile number validation in which the number should start form 789. I got the code which looks like this ^[789]\d{9}$ . However, I dont know if this code is right and what these symbols before the numbers stand for? Can anyone explain me what these symbols stand for?

Comment: Good news, possibly javascript is not needed for this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911092/html-javascript-regex-on-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3Schools offers a really good page about it : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

^ means the begigning of the regex 
[789] means that the string starts by "7" or "8" or "9". 
\d means "any digit".
{9} means 9 times.
$ means the end of string.

Conclusion : You must have a 9 chars long string, which starts with 7,8 or 9 followed by 9 numbers.
So basically, the string might be "7123456789".