# HTML, Javascript. RegEx on numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field for phone numbers. If the first number is 8, it should be automatically removed when a person types it.

If a person starts writing a number with the first number of 0, 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 then it should do nothing, but if the first number is 8 and it goes like 865453 etc., than it should be instantly removed ( or that first number highlighted red ) by JavaScript.

Comment: so you don't want to all 8 as first number. How many numbers to be filled?

Comment: You probably don't want to remove it as the person types. Consider the case of someone trying to enter 885453.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly, you *don't need JavaScript*:

```
<input type="tel" name="phone" pattern="[^8].*"
                                      title="Numbers cannot start with 8" />
```

And it will work even if the user has JavaScript disabled :)