# java script mobile number validation

Tags: javascript

I have two fields mobile number and alternate mobile number.need java script validation.1st number should not be same as 2nd mobile number.I have tried something and it is working. I edited my question, with correct answer
This is html code:

```html
 <div style="color:red" class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="mbno" placeholder="Mobile" name="mbno" maxlength="13" required /></div>
     
<div style="color:red" class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="altmbno" placeholder="Alternate Mobile" name="altmbno" maxlength="13" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.addMethod("mobile_not_same", function(value, element) {  // Method to check if 2 mobile numbers are same or not
   return $('#mbno').val() != $('#altmbno').val()      // mbno and altmbno are input id's
});

$(function(){
 $("#save").prop('disabled', true);
 // validate signup form on keyup and submit
 $("#defaultForm").validate({    // defaultForm is a form id
  rules: {
   altmbno: {
    required: true,
    number : true,
    mobile_not_same: true,
    minlength: 10
   },
   mbno: {
    required: true,
    number : true,
    mobile_not_same: true,
    minlength: 10
   },
  },
  messages: {
   mbno: {
    required: "Please enter 10 digitsmobile number !",
    mobile_not_same: "mobile numbers should not be same",
   },
   altmbno: {
    required: "Please enter 10 digitsmobile number !",
    mobile_not_same: "mobile numbers should not be same",
   },
  }
 })
});

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried already that hasn't worked?

Comment: You haven't shown any effort whatsoever, so I'm not going to just spoon-feed you the answer. But to point you in the right direction, try comparing the values of your inputs on the event you're using to handle the validation.

Comment: You need [this to validate a phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911092/html-javascript-regex-on-numbers), along with some motivation to compare the two numbers by yourself

Comment: you have to try yourself .. its just have to add one line in `js function` with `if` condition

Comment: I have tried something like this:        <script type="text/javascript">
  function check_UN(){
   var  mbno = $("#mbno").val();
   var  altmbno = $("#mbno").val();
if (mbno.value == altmbno.value){

    $("#mobile_error").html("<b>mobile numbers should not be same! </b>");
    $("#mobile_error").show("slow");
}
else{
  
     $("#mobile_error").hide("slow");
     $("#mobile_error").html("");
}
   }
   
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

Question shows **less effort**. Hope you remember next time.
You can easily achieve this using Jquery. Add Id to each input. Code will look like this.

```
<div style="color:red" class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" name="mbno" id="num1" maxlength="13" required /></div>
<div style="color:red" class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alternate Mobile" name="altmbno" id="num2" maxlength="13" /></div>
```

Add script and Use keyup from jquery while typing second mobile number.

```
$("#num2").keyup(function(){
  var bla = $('#num1').val();
  var bla1 = $('#num2').val();
  if(bla === bla1){ 
      console.log('equal');
  }else{
      console.log('not equal');
  }
}
```

If you don't want while typing and just after form submit, then write function and get values of two fields using Jquery (you can also get it by using getElementById). After that compare that two values.

Answer (score -1):

Comparing two numbers should not be that hard

```js
function validate() {
  var mbno = document.getElementById('mbno');
  var altmbno = document.getElementById('altmbno');
  if (mbno.value === altmbno.value) {
    alert("Error! The mobile numbers should not be the same");
  } else {
    alert("Numbers Are OK");
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="color:red" class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="mbno" placeholder="Mobile" name="mbno" maxlength="13" required /></div>

<div style="color:red" class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="altmbno" placeholder="Alternate Mobile" name="altmbno" maxlength="13" /></div>

<button onclick="validate();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Downvoters should at least explain the downvote ...

Comment: I tried your code i'm getting alert but values are storing in database

Comment: @Prajakta The alert is just a demonstration. You shoud only forward the request to your database if the two values are not equal